# libgdx box2d body - Why the body is shaking after reaching the touchpoint position?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, physics

**Problem**

> If the bullet reaches its destination the body is shaking, back and fort from destination to previous position then back again to
>   destination and so on.. and so fort... *Strange behavior*

[image: Visual]

**Sample Code**

```
Vector2 targetPosition =
// Copied target position and subtracted by bullet position
Vector2 targetDirection = targetPosition.cpy().sub(bulletPosition);

float distance = bulletPosition.dst(targetPosition);

float speed = 16;
Vector2 velocity = targetDirection
        .cpy() // Copied target direction
        .nor() // normalize to avoid getting the direction as speed
        .scl(speed);  // scaled by speed
// the distance is not accurate, so we get the time step as defined precision
float DEFINED_PRECISION = Constants.TIME_STEP;
// check if the bullet is near or maybe match the touch point
if(distance >= DEFINED_PRECISION) {
   // move the bullet
   body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
} else {
   // stop the bullet
   body.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your `DEFINED_PRECISION` is too low - you should log out `body's` position in every step (even by adding something like `System.out.println(body.getPosition());` inside your loop) and check wheter it is bigger.

The situation is then that

1. Body is before the target point and it's `distance` is bigger than `DEFINED_PRECISION` so it is being moved forward
2. Body is after the target point and it's `distance` is bigger than `DEFINED_PRECISION` so it is being moved **backward**
3. Body is before the target point and it's `distance` is bigger than `DEFINED_PRECISION`...

And this is why it is shaking :)

First of all you should change your `DEFINED_PRECISION` - check **how much body is being moved in one frame** and this value divided by `2` should be the `DEFINED_PRECISION` (because there is the max distance between body and target between two frames). Also I guess that better than setting `velocity` as `(0,0)` would be setting the target's position to body directly

```
    else {
        body.setTransform(target.getPosition().x, target.getPosition().y, body.getAngle());
    }
```

Of course in case when your step is not very big - then the change will be invisible and the final position will be exactly target's position